# Ion-infinite-scroll inside ion-side-menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use Ion-infinite-scroll inside ion-side-menu, the fetch more function is not being called.

Is it possible to use ion-infinite-scroll inside ion-side-menu?

I added the directive, but the method "loadMore()" is not being called.

This is the line I use:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" ng-if="true" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

and this is the loadMore() method:

```
$scope.loadMore = function() {
  console.log("showMore");
};
```

The complete html is :

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true" cache-view="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content ng-class="{'opaque-content' : isMenuOpen}">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon" menu-toggle="left">
          <img class="menu-icon" src="img/menu-icon.png" />
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <div class="button-icon">
          <img ng-show="showUserImage" class="default-channel-image" src="img/default-channel.png" />
          <img ng-show="showAnonymouseChannel" class="discussion-title-image img-border" src="img/anonymous-icon.png" />
        </div>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left" width="320">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable menu-background">
      <a class="setting-icon-wrapper" href="#/app/preferences" menu-close>
        <img class="settings-icon" src="img/settings.png" />
      </a>
      <form class="search-input-wrapper" ng-submit="search(discussionFilter.data)">
        <input type="text" id="searchFilter" class="search-input" ng-model="discussionFilter.data"  placeholder="Find channels..." ng-change="changeSearch(discussionFilter.data)" ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }'/>
        <div ng-hide="discussionFilter.data != null && discussionFilter.data != ''"  class="search-icon-wrapper" ng-click="search(discussionFilter.data)">
          <i class="fa fa-search fa-2 search-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="discussionFilter.data != null && discussionFilter.data != ''" class="clear-search" data-ng-click="discussionFilter.data = '';search(discussionFilter.data)">
          <img src="img/clear-results.png" class="clear-results">
          </div>

      </form>

    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader channels-header short-header" ng-show="discussions.length > 0" ng-class="">
      <div class="list-items-header channels-header" ng-show="discussions.length > 0">
        <p class="list-header-title">CHANNELS</p>
        <div class="create-channel-area" ng-click="MoveToNewChannel()" menu-close>
          <img class="plus-icon" src="img/plus-button.png"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="channel-headers menu-background" ng-show="discussions.length > 0" ng-click="closeKeyboard()">
      <ion-list class="menu-background menu-list" ng-click="closeKeyboard()">
        <ion-item class="menu-background"  menu-close ng-href="#/app/discussion/{{discussion.id}}" ng-click="closeKeyboard()" ng-repeat="discussion in discussions">

          <div class="menu-channel-text" ng-class="{'subject-regular' : discussion.read}"> {{discussion.subject | truncate_word:18}} </div>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
      <!--<ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore()" immediate-check="false" ng-if="isMenuOpen && showMoreDiscussions" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>-->
    </ion-content>


  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

Added `$scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete'); to the end of my loadMore function.`